# Render Error: "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

I just have this in a new app so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from './components/Header';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header withTitle='AppTitle' />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And `Header` is defined in the aforesaid folder as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 60,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',

    },
    headerText: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#000000',
        letterSpacing: 1,
    },
    headerIcon: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 16,
    }
});


const Header = ({withTitle}) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Icon name='three-bars' size={30} style={styles.headerIcon} />
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>{withTitle}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>    
    );
};


export default Header;
```

I tried various import methods, but the `undefined` leads me to believe that the component is not being returned, though I don't see where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function or component is `exported default` then we import it without curly braces and when it is simply exported then we import it with curly braces.

In your case, you export your `Header default`. So, you have to import it like below:

> `import Header from './components/Header';`

And all the Icons in `react-native-vector-icons` are exported default like:

> `export default Icon;`

So, you have to import it like below:

> `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';`

Comment: These were the issues. One last thing: Do you have a link to some documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing this way

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
```